# Is there a way to use an object's attribute directly in a Perl regex replacement?

Tags: regex, perl, moose

I've got a Perl Moose object that contains an attribute I'd like to use as a replacement string in a regex. The idea is to use something like:

```
$full_string =~ s{FIND_THIS}{$self->replace_string};
```

Where `$self->replace_string` is the Moose object's attribute to use. When run as above, it doesn't work as expected. The regex engine thinks '$self' is the variable and the '->' arrow is just a string. Instead of the value of the of the attribute, the output of the replacement ends up looking something like:

```
ObjectName=HASH(0x7ff458f70778)->replace_string
```

I know that a simple way to overcome this is to drop the string into a new variable. For example:

```
my $new_replace_string = $self->replace_string;
$full_string =~ s{FIND_THIS}{$new_replace_string};
```

My question is if there is a way to avoid creating a new variable and just use the object's attribute directly. (And, ideally without having to add a line of code.) Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to tell Perl the replacement expression is Perl code to evaluate. The replacement value will be the value returned by that code.

```
$full_string =~ s{FIND_THIS}{$self->replace_string}e;
```

But there exists a trick to interpolate the result of an expression into a string literal (which is what the replacement expression is).

```
$full_string =~ s{FIND_THIS}{${\( $self->replace_string )}/;
```

or

```
$full_string =~ s{FIND_THIS}{@{[ $self->replace_string ]}/;
```

The idea is create a reference and interpolate it using a dereference. In the first, the expression is evaluated in scalar context. In the latter, in list context.

Answer (score 2):

`/e` evalutes right side of s/// as an expression:

```
$full_string =~ s/FIND_THIS/$self->replace_string/e;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can throw the [*eval* switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer) ( `/e` ).

```
$full_string =~ s{FIND_THIS}{$new_replace_string}e;
```

Comment: @user1215106, You beat me by 40 seconds for a straight copy of the Perl code, adding an e. I had an explanation and a link.